# How to create a function programatically in R when there is a nested function inside?

Tags: r, metaprogramming, rlang

My goal is to create the following function using code:

```
s <- c(x = 10)
a <- c(i = 3)

model <- function(s, a) {
  with(as.list(c(s, a)), {
    y <- x * i
    y * 10
  })
}

model(s, a)
```

The result should be 300.

I'm parsing another software, and I can extract the equations from that software as strings. So, I need to construct the function's body from those strings.

I've been trying to use rlang library to no avail.

```
library(rlang)

func_body <- "with(as.list(c(s, a)), {
  y <- x * i
  y * 10
})";

foo <- new_function(
  exprs(s =, a = ),
  expr(!!parse(text = func_body))
)
```

Any idea?

Comment: I don't see the motivation. Why not just `model <- function(x, i) {` , called as `model(10,3)`?

Comment: why do you want to write the function this way? why not put `s` and `a` as arguments in the `new_function` directly?

Comment: The motivation is that I'm getting the equations from other software, and they come in the form of strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure your motivation for using `new_function` here but this gives your expected output:

```
library(rlang)

s <- (x = 10)
a <- (i = 3)

foo <- new_function(
  args = pairlist2(s =, a =),
  body = expr(
    with(as.list(c(s, a)), {
      y <- x * i
      y * 10
    })
  )
)

foo(s, a)
#[1] 300
```

If the body is a string use `parse_expr`:

```
foo2 <- new_function(
  args = pairlist2(s =, a =),
  body = parse_expr(
    "with(as.list(c(s, a)), {
      y <- x * i
      y * 10
    })"
  )
)

foo2(s, a)
#[1] 300
```

Answer (score 1):

With base R you can do :

```r
foo <- function(s, a){}
body(foo) <- parse(text=func_body)
foo(s, a)
#> [1] 300
```

An alternative way, still in base R would be:

```r
foo <- as.function(c(alist(s=,a=), parse(text=func_body)[[1]]))
foo(s, a)
#> [1] 300
```

As a side note, in your example the values of `s` and `a` are not use at all, you're just using the values of x and i from the global workspace. You might want :

```r
# cleanup
rm(s,a,x,i)
s <- c(x = 10)
a <- c(i = 3)
foo(s, a)
#> [1] 300
```